# Check All checkbox in level 3 table AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 tables where they are nested  in each other, Inventarios-> Localizacoes -> Etiquetas

I need to add checkbox column for Etiquetas which i already did

```
<table class="table table-sm  dataTable text-center bg-white border border-dark">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xd-2" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Localizações

            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('InventarioID')" class="col-xd-1" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Inventário
                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='InventarioID'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Colaborador')" class="col-xd-2" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Operador
                                 <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Colaborador'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Armazem')" class="col-xd-2" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Armazém
                                 <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Armazem'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Estado')" class="col-xd-1" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Estado
                                 <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Estado'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Total')" class="col-xd-1" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Total
                                 <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Total'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Data')" class="col-xd-2" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Data
                                 <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Data'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xd-1" style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Exportar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-if="showLoader" class="jumbotron">
            <td colspan="8">
                <!-- so this div containing img will be dislpayed only when the showLoader is equal to true-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="p-4">
                            <strong style="color: #526e90">A carregar dados...</strong>
                            <p></p>
                            <div class="lds-hourglass">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- or any other spinner -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="i in inventarios | filter : paginate | filter:searchData:'Colaborador' | orderBy:sortKey:reverse">
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">
                <img src="../../Images/collapse.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="i.expanded" ng-click="i.expanded = false" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                <img src="../../Images/expand.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="!i.expanded" ng-click="i.expanded = true" style="cursor: pointer;" />
            </td>
            <td ng-if="$even">
                <img src="../../Images/collapse.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="i.expanded" ng-click="i.expanded = false" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                <img src="../../Images/expand.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="!i.expanded" ng-click="i.expanded = true" style="cursor: pointer;" />
            </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ i.InventarioID }}</td>
            <td ng-if="$even">{{ i.InventarioID }} </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ i.Colaborador }}</td>
            <td ng-if="$even">{{ i.Colaborador }} </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ i.Armazem }}</td>
            <td ng-if="$even">{{ i.Armazem }} </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">
                <div ng-class="{ 'badge badge-success' : i.Estado, 'badge badge-danger' : !i.Estado }">{{ i.Estado ? 'Aberto' : 'Fechado' }}</div>
            </td>
            <td ng-if="$even">
                <div ng-class="{ 'badge badge-success' : i.Estado, 'badge badge-danger' : !i.Estado }">{{ i.Estado ? 'Aberto' : 'Fechado' }}</div>
            </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe"></td>
            <td ng-if="$even"></td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ i.Data | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}}</td>
            <td ng-if="$even">{{ i.Data | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}} </td>
            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe"></td>
            <td ng-if="$even"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="i.expanded" ng-repeat-end>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="7">
                <table width="100%" class="table table-sm table-bordered dataTable text-center bg-white">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Etiquetas</th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Nº </th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Localização</th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Etiquetas Por Inventariar</th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Etiquetas Inventariadas</th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Válido</th>
                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Precisão (%)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat-start="l in i.Localizacoes">
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">
                                <img src="../../Images/collapse.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="l.expanded" ng-click="l.expanded = false" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                                <img src="../../Images/expand.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="!l.expanded" ng-click="l.expanded = true" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">
                                <img src="../../Images/collapse.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="l.expanded" ng-click="l.expanded = false" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                                <img src="../../Images/expand.png" width="25" class="button button-light" ng-if="!l.expanded" ng-click="l.expanded = true" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ l.LocalizacaoID }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ l.LocalizacaoID }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ l.Referencia }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ l.Referencia }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ l.EtiquetasPorInventariar }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ l.EtiquetasPorInventariar }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ l.EtiquetasInventariadas }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ l.EtiquetasInventariadas }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">
                                <div ng-class="{ 'badge badge-success' : l.IsValid, 'badge badge-danger' : !l.IsValid }">{{ l.IsValid ? 'Sim' : 'Não' }}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">
                                <div ng-class="{ 'badge badge-success' : l.IsValid, 'badge badge-danger' : !l.IsValid }">
                                {{ l.IsValid ? 'Sim' : 'Não' }} </td>
                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ l.Precisao }}</td>
                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ l.Precisao * 100 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-if="l.expanded" ng-repeat-end>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="7">
                                <table width="100%" class="table table-sm table-bordered dataTable text-center bg-white">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Nº </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: #526e90; color: white;">Etiqueta</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-change="selectAll()"></input></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="e in l.Etiquetas">
                                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ e.EtiquetaID }}</td>
                                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ e.EtiquetaID }}</td>
                                            <td ng-if="$even">{{ e.Numero }}</td>
                                            <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color: #ecf4fe">{{ e.Numero}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="e.isChecked" ng-change="selectEtiqueta()">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is the app. I'm not sure how to only run the selected element of the array and loop through that one so in my code i'm running every index of parent array.

```
<script>


        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        app.controller('inventariosCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.searchColumns = ["Inventario", "Operador", "Armazém", "Data"]
            $scope.showLoader = true;
            $http.get("api/inventarios").then(function (response) {
                $scope.showLoader = false;
                $scope.inventarios = response.data;
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.inventarios.length;

                // This property will be bound to checkbox in table header
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes.length; i++) {
                    $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].allItemsSelected = false;
                }
            });

            // This executes when entity in table is checked
            $scope.selectEtiquetas = function () {
                // If any entity is not checked, then uncheck the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes.length; i++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].Etiquetas.length; y++) {
                        if (!$scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].Etiquetas[y].isChecked) {
                            $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].allItemsSelected = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }



                //If not the check the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes.length; i++) {
                    $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].allItemsSelected = true;
                }


                // This executes when checkbox in table header is checked
                $scope.selectAll = function () {
                    // Loop through all the entities and set their isChecked property
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes.length; y++) {
                        for (var y = 0; y < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].Etiquetas.length; y++) {
                            $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].Etiquetas[y].isChecked = $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes[i].allItemsSelected;
                        }
                    }
                };   
            })

    </script>
```

I keep getting undefined when i try to loop through the 2nd nested array... it says Localizacoes are not defined yet they appear inside the object as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined error because your inventarios is also an array. You need an other for loop to loop through inventarios

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventarios.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.inventarios.Localizacoes.length; j++)
    {
        $scope.inventarios[i].Localizacoes[j].allItemsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

or if you know the indexes you can directly access array elements using them without using loops.

```
$scope.inventarios[indexInventarios].Localizacoes[indexLocalizacoes].allItemsSelected = true;
```

Comment: That totally makes sense, forgot i had to loop through that as well. However what i probably need is the 2nd option so i just need to loop through the items from the current nested selected object but that's another option

Comment: @Jackal  I'm glad I could help.